# Re Issue with Textbox, Checkbox, Dropdown

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a little issue with my code not displaying correctly. I have a drop down which when selected hits the back end database, populate/check the checkboxlist accordingly, and populate the textbox if there's value. Let's say I select Honda from the dropdown, the checkbox would check civic and accord since in the database those two value already exist. Once everything bind, I check CRV, CRV would override civic and accord. I want to keep what's auto populated in the textbox and just keep adding on what's checked.

For example: Honda's in the dropdown ... textbox auto populate civic and accord and check box check civic and accord ... I check CRV, this override what I have. So my result is just CRV. I would like it to be civic, accord, CRV. Can someone help? I tried the suggestion but still hasnt resolve my issue. Note, the checkbox's event is SelectedIndexChanged.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim strText As String = ""

For i = 0 To cbCars.Items.Count - 1
    If cbCars.Items(i).Selected Then
        If strText = "" Or strTeethText = Nothing Then
            strText += cbTeeth.Items(i).Text 
        Else
            strText += ", " & cbCars.Items(i).Text
        End If
    End If
Next
txtCars.Text = strText.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem - if cbCars is a CheckedListBox then you should be using [CheckedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems.aspx) or CheckedIndices, and the [ItemCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) event, rather than dealing with selected item(s), which are those item(s) that are highlighted but not necessarily checked.

Comment: so you're saying what i'm doing is wrong? if so, what would be a solution for it?

Comment: @bolo - if you're wanting to work on the checked rather than selected items then yes.

Comment: @ Will -- what would be a solution for my issue?

Comment: @bolo - look at the CheckedItems (or CheckedIndices) collections on the CheckedListBox, and respond to the ItemCheck event to pick up on when an items check state changes.